# Unable to import scalatra-json and json4s-jackson in Scalatra project

Tags: json, scala, scalatra

I want to convert a `ListBuffer[Case Class]` to JSON, I tried using scalatra-json and followed the [documentation guideline](https://scalatra.org/guides/2.3/formats/json.html). I added the following lines to my **buid.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++=   Seq(  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % ScalatraVersion,
"org.json4s"   %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.5.2",)
```

but while doing `jetty:start` I am getting the following error:

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last update for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scalatra:scalatra-json_2.12:2.2.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/wintersoldier/.ivy2/local/org.scalatra/scalatra-json_2.12/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatra/scalatra-json_2.12/2.2.0/scalatra-json_2.12-2.2.0.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalatra/scalatra-json_2.12/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Error downloading org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.7.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/wintersoldier/.ivy2/local/org.json4s/json4s-jackson_2.12/3.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json4s/json4s-jackson_2.12/3.7.0/json4s-jackson_2.12-3.7.0.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.json4s/json4s-jackson_2.12/3.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed 09-Nov-2020, 8:53:38 PM
```

Comment: Looking at [**Mavenrepocitory**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatra/scalatra-json) it seems that the `2.2.0` version of that library was not published for **Scala** `2.12` - Moreover, it seems that is a pretty old version that was only published for pretty old versions of **Scala**. I would recommend you to upgrade those dependencies and if possible **Scala** itself to their latest releases.

Comment: Upgrading the lib version to 2.7 worked :D